# Exception occurred during code generation for the WSDL : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ws/commons/schema/utils/NamespacePrefixList

Tags: eclipse, web-services, soap, wsdl, apache-axis

I am using Tomcat 7 server and Axis 2 1.7 runtime in eclipse.

I have a WSDL file which is generated in Axis 2.

so go for Topdown approach to generate a webservice class (skeleton). I selected my configuration as Axis in server run time. when tried to click finish it is showing following error: "**Exception occurred during code generation for the WSDL  : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ws/commons/schema/utils/NamespacePrefixList**"

I thought it is a jar miss so i first included XmlSchema-1.4.2.jar the error hasn't resolved. so i deleted that jar and tried with latest jar downloaded from java2s (xmlschema-core-2.0.1.jar). Still i have the same problem.

Please help me to solve this issue.

This same issue also persist when trying to create a client from WSDl in eclipse.

Kindly help me to solve this with steps. Thanks

Comment: * I selected my configuration as Axis 2 in server runtime. sry its a Typo by mistake. Kindly help me with solutions

Comment: I have the same issue: I also added `xmlschema-core-2.2.1.jar` in Web App Libraries but it doesn't work. Hope that someone will help us.

Comment: Try Axis2 1.6.X instead of Axis2 1.7.X.

Answer (score 34):

Solved this issue: in `webContent/WEB-INF/lib` add `xmlschema-core-2.2.1.jar`;
then, ensure it is added in Web App Libraries on your build path; finally close and reopen eclipse before generating web service client.
This worked for me.

Comment: Make sure you restart the eclipse - it didn't work for me until I did.

Comment: This solved my issue on Eclipse Neon. Should eclipse be notified so they fix this bug in the WTP project?

Comment: This also worked for me. The only clarification would be that I had to drag and drop the xmlschema-core-2.2.1.jar into the webContent/WEB-INF/lib folder in Eclipse's project explorer. Just adding the xmlschema-core-2.2.1.jar   as external library in the project's build path didn't work. Also, it's fundamental to restart Eclipse for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

In my case this error is occasioned  for using  **axis2-1.7.3**, my solution was change and use **axis2-1.6.4**