# Trying to start webservice using Tomcat server in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, tomcat, servlets

I'm a beginner trying to create a web service using Apache Tomcat 7 and eclipse, I have completed these following steps.
 - Setting AXIS2's runtime location to where it was installed.
 - Creating a dynamic web project with a simple class called OperatorClass and a method that just adds 2 integers.
 - Created web service on the dynamic web project, using the OperatorClass and running it on an Apache Tomcat 7 server.

Once I have reached the AXIS2 homepage, after clicking on "Services", I receive these errors which I have no idea what they mean nor do I know how to solve it. Hoping someone here could help.

```
HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet AxisServlet threw exception
type Exception report
message Servlet.init() for servlet AxisServlet threw exception
description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet AxisServlet threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
root cause
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ws/commons/schema/resolver/URIResolver
    org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer.deploy(ModuleDeployer.java:128)
    org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:144)
    org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:585)
    org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init(RepositoryListener.java:264)
    org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init2(RepositoryListener.java:66)
    org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.<init>(RepositoryListener.java:61)
    org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadRepository(DeploymentEngine.java:152)
    org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(WarBasedAxisConfigurator.java:233)
    org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:620)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:471)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ws.commons.schema.resolver.URIResolver
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer.deploy(ModuleDeployer.java:128)
    org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:144)
    org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:585)
    org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init(RepositoryListener.java:264)
    org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init2(RepositoryListener.java:66)
    org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.<init>(RepositoryListener.java:61)
    org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadRepository(DeploymentEngine.java:152)
    org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(WarBasedAxisConfigurator.java:233)
    org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:620)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:471)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Did you have installed Axis2 1.7.1? If so, trying this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36497872/2217336.
Also, put  `xmlschema-core-2.2.1.jar`  library in tomcat's `lib/` folder.