# Axis2 Soap WS client: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ws/commons/schema/XmlSchema

Tags: java, apache, web-services, soap, apache-axis

I had an issue today while generating a SOAP Web Service client using Apache Axis 2 1.7.4 and Eclipse Neon 4.6.3RC3.

The way I was generating the Web Service client was:

1. Right click on my WSDL > "Web Services" > "Generate client"
2. Select "Apache Axis2" as Web Service Runtime and "Tomcat 7" as Server Runtime (all the other options are defaults)
3. Click on "Finish"

The error I got was:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ws/commons/schema/XmlSchema
```

[image: Error]

Although there are plenty of answers on StackOverflow about this issue, none really solved this for me, so I thought that I would share what did fixed my problem (along with a summary of other proposed solutions) hoping that in the future this post will help somebody.

If anybody wants to add his knowledge to this post, go ahead and leave a comment/answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. Add missing XML schema dependency**

In many cases, this seems related to a missing dependency on the project. The missing dependency seems to be `xmlschema-core-2.2.1.jar`. You can add it on a Maven project like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.ws.xmlschema</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlschema-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36497872/4921205

If you are not using Maven, you can download the libraries and add them manually to your classpath.

**Important Note:** for some reasons, it seems that even if you add the new libraries, you will need to restart your Eclipse before the new libraries are picked up.

**2. Use Axis2 1.6.x**

Since this seems a bug introduced in `Axis2 1.7.x`, another possible solution may be to use `1.6.x` jar if possible.

**3. Revert the Dynamic Web Module project facet to version 2.3**

This was what actually did the trick for me. The project was using the Dynamic Web Module 2.5 facet and that doesn't seem to work properly with this Axis version (I was aware that 3.0 had problems). After switching to 2.3 generating only a developement client worked. Here's how to do it:

1. Right click on the project -> "Properties" -> "Project Facets"
2. Select version of "Dynamic Web Module" and set it to 2.3 from the right dropdown (if this window is empty you may have to convert the project in faceted form by clicking on the link provided in the same window).
3. Right click on your WSDL -> "Web Services" -> "Generate client"

[image]

4. Set the Develop client only option by dragging down the meter on the left, set your server runtime and choose Axis2 as your Web service runtime.

   [image]
5. Click on "Finish" and you should see your Web Service client generated under the `src` folder.

Answer (score 1):

Manually copy **xmlschema-core-2.2.1.jar** from $AXIS2_HOME/lib to the Eclipse project directory **WebContent/WEB-INF/lib**, close and reopen eclipse before generating web service client.

Comment: https://yiingw.wordpress.com/2018/02/12/axis2-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-ws-commons-schema-utils-namespaceprefixlist/